# How to properly Append NSMutableData and NSData with JSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

im trying to append nsdata to nsmutabledata, on my first attempt, it seems fine, but when i get new contents of nsdata and append it to my nsmutabledata, it seems fine, but my deserialized dictionary returns nil, please  help guys. :)

```
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myMutableDictionary options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableData * myMutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:jsonData];

[myMutableData appendData:jsonData];

NSDictionary *deSerializedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myMutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: If you simply concat two `JSON`s, result is (most likely) not a valid `JSON`, that is why `+JSONObjectWithData` is returning `nil`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to overwrite the nsdata and merge it in my nsmutabledata, and is it possible to convert it back to jsondata again? thank you very much for the info. :D

Comment: You should not think in the terms if `NSData`, but rather `JSON` objects - there is no "merge" operation with `JSON`. Do you want to create an `JSON` array containing two `JSON` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an absolute, one hundred percent principle, if you have NSData containing a valid JSON object, then after adding anything but white space characters the NSData cannot possibly contain a valid JSON object anymore.

As a special case, if you have TWO NSData containing valid JSON objects, then their concatentation can NEVER contain a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You should write one JSON function.Why do you want to add NSData to NSMutableData?. If you follow below coding,you can understand easily.

```
//just give your URL instead of my URL

 NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662452/how-to-properly-append-nsmutabledata-and-nsdata-with-jsonserialization"]];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

 [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

 NSError *err;

 NSURLResponse *response;

 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

 NSLog("the jsonDict is - %@",jsonDict);
```